# Pandas efficiently add or insert into sequential index series (perhaps by extending pandas?)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

With respect to [calculating the POC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578058/efficiently-calculating-point-of-control-with-pandas) for stock data, I'm witnessing sluggishness due to constantly creating a new pandas series object every time I want to increment my volume or time @ price series.

The following is an example of my running list of time @ price; let's call it `tap`:

```
8.83    1
8.84    1
8.85    3
8.86    2
8.87    1
8.88    2
dtype: int64
```

As per the POC post you can see that I create a new pd.Series object with an index that contains the entire bar's price range (let's call this `bar`). The current implementation yields expected results, however it's slow when run over a very large data set. For this example, assume `bar`'s index ranges from `8.87:8.90` and its values are filled with `1`). Running `tap.add(bar, fill_value=0)` results in:

```
8.83    1
8.84    1
8.85    3
8.86    2
8.87    2
8.88    3
8.89    1
8.90    1
dtype: int64
```

This is correct. But if I were to avoid creating the `bar` series object altogether and instead increment `tap` by:

`tap[frame.low:frame.high] += 1`

It only increments existing values but ignores the new ones resulting in:

```
8.83    1
8.84    1
8.85    3
8.86    2
8.87    2
8.88    3
dtype: int64
```

Is there a way of extending pandas such that I can create a step-wise incremented index series that behaves the way I need it to in this situation?

Comment: It shouldn't really take that much time to create a simple Series. Maybe like 70ms for 10M rows. Are you certain that is the step that's your bottle neck? I mean **have** to define the total set of rows in your output somehow.

Comment: And how much memory will that take up? What happens when I try to do operations on that kind of object? I'm operating on this thing tens of thousands of times.

Comment: Also, there's no upper limit to prices. I simply can't declare all of the prices ahead of time. The script won't be an issue during runtime - it's only an issue when parsing historical data.